# query string from .htaccess not returning double forward slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /core/pageNotFound.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteBase /
Options -Multiviews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^share/?$ share.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^share/(.*?)/?$ share.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

But the issue is when I have a `URL` like this

```
https://www.example.com/share/https://testsite.com
```

And when I try to echo it out in my PHP page

```
echo $url = $_GET['url'];
```

This is what I get

```
https:/testsite.com
```

Instead of

```
https://testsite.com
```

The forward slash after `https:` becomes one instead of 2. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `RewriteRule` merges multiple slashes into one, possibly due to the definition of URI paths in [RFC1630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1630) stating

> [...] when it contains slashes, these must imply a hierarchical
> structure.

A workaround is to capture it in the `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/share/(.*?)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ share.php?url=%1 [L]
```

The same "problem" also happens when using NGINX instead of Apache. In NGINX you can disable merging of slashes by adding this to your config:

```
merge_slashes off;
```